# Start a GUI in NetworkManager if-up.d script

Tags: bash, scripts, openvpn

I was wondering if it was possible to start a graphical application from a bash script when my openvpn is up.

I was trying with command like this:

```
gksudo -u username "sh -c '(/usr/bin/firefox &) &> /dev/null'"
```

or

```
sudo su -c '(/usr/bin/firefox &) &> /dev/null' username
```

it works in bash script but it doesn't seems to work in if-up.d on connection with openvpn.

Does anyone have an idea?